# How do I use Spring embedded database initialization scripts during the integration-test phase?

Tags: spring, integration-testing, embedded-database

I can use Spring to create and initialize embedded databases either programmatically:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    database = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("schema.sql")
            .addScript("init.sql")
            .build();
    ....
}
```

or via Spring configuration:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:init.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Here my scripts `schema.sql` and `init.sql` are stored in the directory `src/test/resources`.  So if tests using the embedded databse are run with:

```
mvn test
```

then the files, being in `src/test/resources` are available, and everything is fine.

But now suppose I want to instead use the embedded database together with an embedded web server (Jetty or embedded Tomcat) in an *integration test*, run via

```
mvn integration-test
```

Now in this late phase, I want to do an almost end-to-end test that hitting certain urls for the web service return the expected HTTP responses, assuming certain data in the embedded database.  But at this point, the war deployed in the embedded webserver does not have files from `src/test/resources` so my initialization scripts are not present, and I get the error

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [schema.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Now everything *will* work if I put the scripts in `src/main/resources` but these scripts are only for filling up an embedded database for *testing* and they do not *belong* in the war file at all.  Does anyone know how to set up an integration test so that an emedded database can be used, without polluting the actual war file that will be deployed?

I was hoping that Spring's embedded database initialization could use something other than a file.  I thought about JNDI but that would seem to require polluting the web.xml file with a resource definition for test data which would (again) appear in the deployable war.  Or perhaps there are options using cargo?  Some programmatic tricks with Spring that I don't know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="file:///${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="file:///${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/init.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Comment: ${project.basedir} - Can maven variables be used inside Spring context?